# how to use the name of the input file in sed replace

Tags: sed, filenames

i have several files in which i want to replace a certain word with the name of the file itself..

for example i have 2 files named test1.txt  and test2.txt

both files are equal and  look like

```
bla1,bla2,temp
bla2,bla3,temp
```

with the sed i want to replace the word temp   with the name of the file itself

so after the sed operation i have 2 different files

test1.txt , which looks like :

```
bla1,bla2,test1
bla2,bla3,test1
```

test2.txt,  which looks like :

```
bla1,bla2,test2
bla2,bla3,test2
```

so my question ... how do i use the actual name of the input file itself  as part of the replace command?

```
sed "s/temp/  ??filename??/   ???  "    *.txt
```

thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can reference the filename using `sed` although I could be wrong. You would probably use a *shell hack*. A better aproach to substitute all occurrences of `temp` with the filename would be the following `awk` script:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/temp/,FILENAME)}1' file
```

Comment: Damn! I post my ridiculously long answer without realising there's a variable in awk. Nice one.

Comment: @user3099593 on stackoverflow the way you show that you are impressed with an answer is to upvote it *(when you get enough rep)*. You should now accept the answer that was most useful to you by clicking the tick mark next to that answer.

Comment: Some addtl questions ...      1)   i want to strip the file type of the file name   2) i want to put ";" surrounding the file name  ;filename; 3) i want to write the output back to the same file that i am currently reading and changing.. so in my use case i have a file filter of *.txt which should process dozens of files .. just directing the output to a file with > outfile will end me up with all data from all files in one output file.. so how actually to reuse the current file also as the name of the output file .. or is that one open and do i need a temporary file   ... great thx to all !

Answer (score 1):

use awk, awk has `FILENAME` variable:

```
awk '{sub(/temp/,FILENAME)}7' yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$NF=FILENAME}1' file
```

The difference between this and the sub() solutions is that this will work even if the word "temp" exists elsewhere in your file, e.g. if "bla1" contains the word "temperature".

If you need to strip ".txt" from the file name as it appears from your posted desired output, tweak it to:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {t=FILENAME; sub(/\.txt$/,"",t); $NF=t}1' file
```

You can probably edit FILENAME itself but I find it best not to mess with the builtin variables if you don't have to.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the example was representative, if it is this would be a better solution.

Comment: If it's not then we're shooting in the dark :-)

Comment: Aren't we always.. just sometimes the OP have brighter touches than others and are facing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a little bit of bash to help you out, if that's available.

```
find . -name "test*.txt" -type f | awk -F '/' '{print $2;}' | while read file; do sed -i "s|temp|$file|" ./$file; done
```

That's a kind of hacky adaptation of a script I have to do something similar. It can undoubtedly be shortened.

Comment: No. No, no, no. And finally - no. :-) Not only is the above lengthy and inefficient, it has several insidious bugs that will trip you up for various file names.

Comment: You don't like it? :)

Comment: I'm now rewriting my command to use awk and gsub, though I don't think I'm going to be able to get around creating a temp file. Oh, for a combination of FILENAME and sed -i.

Comment: That would be `gawk -i inplace 'script' file` with gawk 4.1.0 and later releases.

Comment: Nice! I'll need debian to add it to the wheezy repo, but at least I know a fix is coming.

Comment: It was my suggestion to the gawk providers to create it and I'm very grateful that they did but honestly I rarely use it, just if it's convenient to do something as part of a `find -exec awk` or `find | xargs awk`. Any other time I feel `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file` is as easy to write and IMHO a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

no sed internal variable for the file name so you need some previous batch command for a generic process

```
for FileName in MyFileShellFilter
 do
    cat <> ${FileName} | sed "s|,temp$|,${FileName}|"
 done
```

just be carrefull with file name used, they normaly don't have `\` but could have `&` that are `s//` special meaning. I use `|` as separator to allow `/` in file name but for this reason, no unescaped `|` are allowed in file name (normaly not)

Comment: Also watch out for file names containing spaces, or *s or any other globbing character as those will cause undesirable results and be aware that the shell could decide to overwrite your file before it opens it for reading so you could end up with an empty file.

Comment: good remarks (+1), i have to surround "${filename}" at cat level. The *sis normaly expanded by the shell before pass into the loop.

Comment: Yeah, the biggest issue really is that `cat <> file | foo` can be interpreted by the shell such that the first thing the shell does is the `> file` part so it immediately zaps your input file and THEN the `cat < file |...` afterwards on the now empty file.

Comment: I got same remark on another post and after a test, it seems that it depend on shell/OS. On cigwin and linux SH/BASH/KSH it fail contrary  to my daily AIX/KSH. SO this is a 'big' limitation

Comment: I'm not sure its even that consistent, I think it might depend on the context in which you're trying to execute the commands too. The rule of thumb is simply to never try to write to the same file you're reading.

Answer (score 0):

with `xargs`:

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt | xargs -I FILE -L 1 sed 's/temp/FILE/' FILE
```

The filename cannot have: newlines, slashes, ampersand, single quote.